# The PNG's that I put into my res/drawable folder will not show up in code

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am trying to access a PNG that I put into my drawable-mdpi folder. However, when I type in R.drawable. my resources aren't in the huge list of default resources. Here is where im trying to declare it. I have tried cleaning my project, refreshing folder, restarting eclipse and none of it works. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be due to Imports

choose the correct import for **R** ..

remove `import android.R;`

and add `import yourpackagename.R`

Comment: Dude omg ive been stressing about this issue for the past 3 hours now looking on how to fix it and you just did it in 3 minutes thank you SO MUCH :))! Why did it not work when the import was just regular android.R?

Comment: @NathanWick because it will instead try to find the resource from Android's standard resource, not your app's resource.

Comment: thank you guys so much, I can finally move on with my app :)!

Comment: The explaintion which NathanWick given is right :)
All the best.